# RSpec/Capybara Selenium Safari issue

Tags: selenium, rspec, safari, capybara

The code below works with when running Chrome and Firefox. I am having issues with Safari using apple's new driver, however. Safari loads up, maximises window, but it will not input anything into the text fields. Please advise?

```
require 'capybara/rspec'

Capybara.configure do |config|
  config.run_server = false
  config.default_driver = :selenium
  config.app_host = 'https://www.fake.com'
end

Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :safari)
end

Capybara.page.driver.browser.manage.window.maximize
Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 10

describe "Entering invalid credentials,", :type => :feature do
  it "should prompt an error message." do
    visit '/#/login'


#Code below does not work
    fill_in 'Email', with: 'fake@email.com'
    fill_in 'Password', with: 'fake'
    click_button 'Log In'

    end
end
```

: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEG6f.png

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please make sure you add the code snippet itself, not an image of it. You can also refer to this to get started with asking questions on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What versions of the relevant gems/drivers/browsers are you using?

Comment: rspec (3.4.0)
capybara (2.11.0)
selenium (3.0)
Safari (10.0) with Apple's built in webdriver

Comment: I downloaded Safari Technology Preview.  Would you happen to know how I can modify my code to load that vs instead of standard Safari?